# Getting Error: Object of type 'archiveDir' and path '....vbproj.zip' cannot be created while doing Packageweb configuration with teamcity

Tags: deployment, web, package, teamcity

I am trying to configure packageweb with teamcity. But getting the following error:-

[image]

I am passing it the parameters for publishing and also it is not transforming the config file.  even that parameter is mentioned in the file. any idea what I am doing wrong here.

PAcakgeweb ref: http://sedodream.com/2012/03/14/PackageWebUpdatedAndVideoBelow.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, so while I'm sure you don't have a use for this answer eight months later, I will post this anyway in case someone else experiences the same issue.

Assuming that you're using TeamCity to compile your project, you'll need to add the PackageWeb targets file into the web project file so that it runs the SlowCheetah transform s at compile time.

For me, this meant unloading the web project in Visual Studio and adding in the following imports target right down at the bottom of the file, just before the closing /Project tag;

```
<Import Project="_Package\Sedodream.Package.targets" />
```

You can read more about this [here](http://sedodream.com/2011/12/12/SlowCheetahXMLTransformsFromACIServer.aspx) and [here](http://sedodream.com/2012/12/24/SlowCheetahBuildServerSupportUpdated.aspx).